# How to make HTML interact with a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Hello everyone, I have a project and I want to create an MVP: Minimum Viable Product. 
And I have html pages ready but I don't know how to make them interact with databases, preferably MySQL. 
I need the simplest way to be able to POST and GET data from a database, PHP or Rails. 
IF there's just one simple tutorial or a small ebook to read, I'll be so thankful. 
  
I have to the end of the month to create the MVP, about 20 days or so, and I really want to make that happen and I was gonna learn the whole Rails just to do that, but it'll take time you know! 
Thanks for your time and I hope that you might help me :)

Comment: @ceejayoz Dont be rude

Comment: First you need to learn about PHP, PHP connect to database and you can manipulate the HTML. I have 35 of XP with program.

Comment: If you're serious about getting this done in 20 days, you need to hire a developer who already knows how to do this. Asking for links to tutorials or ebooks is expressly off-topic here.

Comment: Have you ever google it before you want a ebook to learn something?

Comment: I did google it but I got just some vague stuff ... and no I can't hire anyone at the moment, I have to it manually ... also no need for ebooks and videos if there's a simple way or explanation to help me with here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make HTML directly interacting with database. You should create server-side application, which answer queries generated by HTML forms, JS queries, etc. I am PHP developer, I like this language, so I recommend you using it in your solution.

You can read about connecting PHP to MySQL database here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

There you have basic information about handling data sent by POST:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

If you have any troubles during develop proccess try Google before, then if didn't find answer ask **specific and well described** question on Stack Overflow.

Best luck!

Comment: i down-vote answers to obviously about to be closed off topic questions. and w3schools should never be used as a reputable source of coding help

Comment: Okay and I know that HTML can't do that, I already said it and I'm sure that my question is very specific !

Comment: Despite someone did down-vote. I think this solution suits better for OP's necessities. So, I gonna Upvote and hope Owner could search better from the internet about PHP and MySQL. There are many other tutorials websites he can learn from it.

Comment: so be kind enough to share few!

Comment: @MohamedBouasria I gave you base to kick-start your project. Try these links and then google similar results

Comment: I am reading them and maybe I found what I wanted on the second link!

Comment: @MohamedBouasria I am really glad. If you think my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: Yeah, I will ... coz it did show me what I needed, thanks ;) (y)